# How do I prevent DIV tag starting a new line?

Tags: html, css

I want to output a single line of text to the browser that contains a  tag. When this is rendered it appears that the DIV causes a new line. How can I include the content in the div tag on the same line - here is my code.

```
<?php 
  echo("<a href=\"pagea.php?id=$id\">Page A</a>") 
?>
<div id="contentInfo_new">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="getData.php?id=<?php echo($id); ?>"></script>
</div>
```

I have tried to tidy it up here. How can I have this display on a single line?

Comment: Just to point out, you don't need the brackets when using echo. `echo $id;` is as valid as `echo($id);`.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The `div` tag is a block element, causing that behavior.

You should use a `span` element instead, which is inline.

If you *really* want to use `div`, add `style="display: inline"`.  (You can also put that in a CSS rule)

Comment: Only `display: inline` contradicts what the DIV is for, so please don't do it! Use the span instead.

Comment: I'm well aware of that; that's why I wrote `if you really want to`.

Comment: A div is defined as a division of a page, prior to HTML5. Its not defined with any presentation characteristics.  In other words a div is semantically appropriate according to its definition based upon the content and elements it contains.  As a result it is perfectly fine to set a div to display:inline and not violate any semantics or standard definition.

Comment: In my case, I couldn't use span, because I wanted to defined a break-word word wrap property, and those only work for block type elements. But I couldn't use div, because I didn't want a new line. So instead I used `display: inline-block` and a div element. Say what you will about style, but this solved both problems.

Comment: It did not worked for me! I expected it expanding the cell that div is in, but no change happened

Comment: how to set fixed width for span then

Comment: I have applied style="display:inline-block;" in every div which i wanted in one line and it worked well.

Answer (score 50):

I am not an expert but try `white-space:nowrap;`

The white-space property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: The value `"inherit"` is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a `!DOCTYPE`. IE9 supports `"inherit"`.

Comment: Great when you need inline-block elements not to wrap at the end of the line when you have `overflow: hidden` on the wrap element and you move it according to the parent "on the background" :)

Comment: This should be the answer. with `span` along it doesn't work and still breaks to next line. With `span` and `white-space:nowrap;` it doesn't break to next line.

Answer (score 17):

`div` is a block element, which always takes up its own line.

use the `span` tag instead

Comment: You are confusing presentation for function.  A div takes up its own line because it is presented as display:block by default and for no other reason.

Comment: But span also creates a line break before and after?

Answer (score 8):

Add `style="display: inline"` to your div.

Answer (score 5):

use float:left on the div and the link, or use a span.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer in 2022:

If you are using 2 div element, `white-space: nowrap` won't works, instead wrap them by a `div` by `display: flex` along with `flex-wrap: nowrap` (which is default enabled).

This solution work well when you have multiple divs in a row, but you need 2 of them always on the same row when responsive in small screen device. `inline` solution can't achieve this (unless with nowrap).

```css
div.wrapper-whitespace, div.wrapper-whitespace-with-inline {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.wrapper-whitespace-with-inline > div.item {
  display: inline;
}

div.wrapper-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* this is default */
}

div.item {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>div</div>
<div class='item'>div</div>

<br>

<div class='wrapper-whitespace'>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class='wrapper-whitespace-with-inline'>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class='wrapper-flex'>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
  <div class='item'>div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do a break line is using span with CSS style parameter white-space: nowrap;

```
span.nobreak {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

or
span.nobreak {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example directly in your HTML

```
<span style='overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;'> YOUR EXTENSIVE TEXT THAT YOU CAN´T BREAK LINE ....</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
overflow-x: scroll;
width: max-content;
```

Worked for me, hope this helps someone else.

(Use case: I had a lot of divs in a row that were breaking to the next line, but I wanted the user to scroll to the right instead in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Use css property - white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="float: left;">
<?php 
  echo("<a href=\"pagea.php?id=$id\">Page A</a>") 
?>
</div>
<div id="contentInfo_new" style="float: left;">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="getData.php?id=<?php echo($id); ?>"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: terrible idea to use javascript + php, when you can be fine with only css.

Comment: @Piero Why do you say that?  A backend is usually needed for a front end app

Comment: @Curious true, but backend should be dealing with backend things like calculations and data handling, while frontend should be left for browsers to process. This reduces server load and improves user experience. This is in general terms. In this particular case, however, <a href="pagea.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Page A</a> would be good enough. And with getData.php, why to have php parse and output javascript if this can be handled by apache? Like so: src="getData.js?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use:

```
#contentInfo_new br {display:none;}
```