# Combine PHP echo and regular html output on same line

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script that calculates a special date depending on the real date and then outputs the data with an echo that is then displayed on my webpage. That works fine but I want to add clickable text to that same line next to it. I have the clickable text working but it appears on the line below it and messes up the formatting, how can I make it so they appear both on the same line?

Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
<strong><?php echo "Output "; ?></strong><?php echo $outputVal; ?>
```

Then the HTML I want to add:

```
<div id="hide_cal">Click to open</div>
<div id="hidden_cal">
<div id="cal"></div>
<p>Date: <input class="target" type="text" id="date" readonly></p>
</div>
```

**How I want to display:**

Output ---- Click to open

**How its coming out:**

Output ----

Click to open

I've tried using the "." between the PHP variable and the html code but I think I must be doing something wrong with it, and I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: This has to do with your css styling and layouts, my assumption is the divs are being stacked. This should not be related to php + html combination - if you view the source, it probably appears as you expect it.

Comment: use inline tags instead of block tags. or use css to transform block to inline tags by using `display : inline`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826735/how-do-i-prevent-div-tag-starting-a-new-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like...

```
<?php echo "<p><strong>'Output'</strong> $outputVal <a href=#>Click to open</a></p>"; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could style them with `display: inline-block`. But that's not a php answer so it may be considered outside the scope of the question.