# Any1 know how to fix so div dont start a new line?

Tags: html

Any1 knwo to fix my html?

---

```
    <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: pcdown;
        src: url(pdown.ttf);
    }
    .tiny {
        font-size: 29px;
        position: absolute; right: 10;
    }
    #money {
        font-family: pcdown;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: white;
        padding: 4px;
    text-shadow:
       -1px -1px 0 #000,
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
         1px 1px 0 #000;
            }

    #container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40; right: 40;
    }
</style>
```

```
</div>
<div style="display: inline" id="container">
    <div style="display: inline" id="money"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/0cd06472f3592108d5d5ae080693e835.png" height="32" width="32">
    <div style="display: inline" id="cash"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I have a FiveM server and i trying to change money (wallet) icon for client and i have tried 5 times now but i dont succed so now i will put it up online

Comment: This is a poorly written question, unclear what you are asking. Please review documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I dont know why the other div tag is not in the code tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent DIV tag starting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826735/how-do-i-prevent-div-tag-starting-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0):

there seems like there is extra div close tag  at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Flexbox this should give you what you are trying to acheive.

```
  #container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
   }
```

Comment: Yes i want them side by side CSS Grind is it a program?